query table based on YEAR(col1) = dropdown cell value
I'm trying to use a drop down menu to pick a year value to summarize my date based on that year.
YEAR    2021    <== Drop Down Menu  
            
DATE    EMPLOYEE    JOB #   CITY
1/2/2020    JIM 25011   Statesville
3/4/2022    BOB 36054   Asheville
6/3/2021    LARRY   32009   Asheville
4/5/2024    LARRY   42027   Johnson City
8/4/2024    JIM 26026   Franklin
9/1/2023    JIM 28032   Greenville
10/3/2024   BOB 25013   Greenville
5/24/2021   LARRY   25019   Franklin

enter image description here
DATE is in Date format.
I tried: (in cell E4)
=QUERY(A4:D11,"SELECT A WHERE YEAR(A) = B1")

and I get an error: Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: B1
I tried:
=QUERY(A4:D11,"SELECT A WHERE YEAR(A) = 2024")

and it works.
What am I missing?


With a slight modification to your current formula:
=QUERY(A4:D11,"SELECT A WHERE YEAR(A) = "&B1, 0)


outside the ""  I put =QUERY(A4:D11,"SELECT A WHERE YEAR(A) = "%B1) and now get a Formula Parse Error

Oops.  I should have used & not %.  It works now.  Thanks.

@DanGill see What should I do when someone answers my question?

Filter Data by Selected Year
You can also try using the FILTER formula as an alternative solution:
=FILTER(A4:A11,ARRAYFORMULA(year(A4:A11))=B1)

Sample Output:

Reference(s):
ARRAYFORMULA
FILTER function

filter() is an array enabler, so no arrayformula() is required there.
